# Validating Radio Button and text fields using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, google-forms

I am trying to validate entries on a form and before passing them into google sheets.

My form works fine when validating email field however i am unable to figure out what i am doing wrong with the radio button field and the text area field.

I have read so many posts on this and i am getting confused. I believe i'm at confused about 'error' and '.control-group'. please find my code below.

I will also like my custom forms to load on my website instead of the google forms when there is an error while filling up the form.

Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Handle form submission
    $('#ss-form').submit(function(e) {
        var button = $('input[type=submit]', this),
            data = $(this).serialize();

        e.preventDefault();
        if (validate($(this))) {
            button.button('loading');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1HNUn0m70hGAiewLV2WfarDtu4kwLJoJrmtS0PjX3RAM/formResponse",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: data,
                complete: function() {
                    button.button('reset');
                    // After submission, redirect to main page
                    window.location = 'http://qwameselase.wix.com/black-n-beautiful#!contact/c1n3j';
                }
            });
        }

        // All fields are required
        function validate(#ss-form) {

            $('.control-group').removeClass('error');
            $('input, textarea', #ss-form).each(function() {
                var tag = $(this)[0].tagName.toLowerCase(),
                    type = $(this).attr('type');

                // Validate radio buttons
                if (tag === 'input' && type === 'radio') {
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    if ($('[name="' + name + '"]:checked').length < 1) {
                        $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('error');
                    }
                }

                // Validate text fields
                if ((tag === 'input' && type === 'text') || tag === 'textarea') {
                    if ($(this).val() === '' && !$(this).parent().hasClass('radio')) {
                        $(this).parent().parent().addClass('error');
                    }
                }

                // Validate email fields
                if (tag === 'input' && type === 'email'){
                    function validateEmail(email) {
                        var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                        return re.test(email);
                    }

                }

            });

            if ($('.control-group.error').length < 1) return true;
            $('.control-group.error').length

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.control-group.error').offset().top - 20
            }, 500);

            return false;
        }
    });
</script>

<form id="ss-form" method="POST" onsubmit="" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1HNUn0m70hGAiewLV2WfarDtu4kwLJoJrmtS0PjX3RAM/formResponse?embedded=true">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="entry_244604360">First Name</label>
                <input id="entry_244604360" type="text" name="entry.244604360" value="" maxlength="100">
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <label for="entry_403969165">Last Name</label>
                <input id="entry_403969165" type="text" name="entry.403969165" value="" maxlength="100">
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <label for="entry_1520202759">E-Mail</label>
                <input id="entry_1520202759" type="email" name="entry.1520202759" value="">
        </div><br>
        <div>
            <label for="entry_294268486">Contact Number</label>
                <input id="entry_294268486" type="text" name="entry.294268486" value="" maxlength="15">
        </div>                                          
    </fieldset><Br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Canvas Type</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="entry_1505307714">Canvas Type</label><br><br>
                <input id="group_1123680937_1" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="Booking Only">Book a spot, pick canvas at event RM 50<br><br><br>
                <label>
                    <input id="group_1123680937_2" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="4x4single" />
                    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/253d02_dec03f3ad51c403e945281f6ee98240f.jpg_srb_p_600_556_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srb" style="max-width:15%" alt="40x40x1 / Single / RM 195">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="group_1123680937_3" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="4x4diptych" />
                    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/253d02_805d3463f30f48d9b814791099c23a95.jpg_srb_p_746_378_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srb" style="max-width:30%" alt="40x40x2 / Diptych / RM 325">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="group_1123680937_4" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="4x4triptych" />
                    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/253d02_133bac604e744812aaa82e8c11f6d63b.jpg_srb_p_1106_409_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srb" style="max-width:40%" alt="40x40 / Triptych / RM 455">
                </label><br><br><br>
                <label>
                    <input id="group_1123680937_5" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="4x9single" />
                    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/253d02_add84feb205b4ffe9d2a31bf6ff5d7a6.jpg_srb_p_600_567_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srb" style="max-width:15%" alt="40x90 / Single / RM 350">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="group_1123680937_6" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="4x9diptych" />
                    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/253d02_22045721297f4b3c9e8f1c46d9bb0bec.jpg_srb_p_600_567_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srb" style="max-width:30%" alt="40x90 / Diptych / RM 610">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input id="group_1123680937_7" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="4x9triptych" />
                    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/253d02_cffba0d8eee742f2b24c815b310240f0.jpg_srb_p_704_525_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srb" style="max-width:40%" alt="40x90 / Triptych / RM 865">
                </label><br><br><br>
                <label>
                    <input id="group_1123680937_8" type="radio" name="entry.1123680937" value="6x10single" />
                    <img src="http://static.wixstatic.com/media/253d02_28767a3b1e694403846cb80f04ab1338.jpg_srb_p_600_567_75_22_0.50_1.20_0.00_jpg_srb" style="max-width:20%" alt="60x100 / Single / RM 525">
                </label><br>

        </div>
    </fieldset><Br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Remarks</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="entry_508497383">Comments</label><br>
            <textarea id="entry_508497383" rows="3" cols="100" name="entry.508497383" value=""></textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset><Br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Get in Touch</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="entry_1014633536">Notify me of upcoming workshops?</label><br>

            <input id="group_1558721004_1" type="radio" name="entry.1558721004" value="Yes" /> Yes <Br>             
            <input id="group_1558721004_2" type="radio" name="entry.1558721004" value="No" /> No <Br>           
        </div>
    </fieldset><Br><Br>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: have a look at this portion `function validate(#ss-form) {$('.control-group').removeClass('error');$('input, textarea', #ss-form).each(function() {` error `SyntaxError: illegal character`

Comment: @Shehary: What am i supposed to be looking out for in that area? I had that suspicion as well but not sure what I've done wrong there nor how to fix it. Is there any syntax error I'm overlooking?

Comment: this is the syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` at this line  `function validate(#ss-form) {` and this is never seen `(#ss-form)` either it should be `$(this)` or this whole line should be `$("#ss-form").validate({`

Comment: and onwards i see error here `$('.control-group').removeClass('error');` and here `$('input, textarea', #ss-form).each(function() {` in 2nd code again this `#ss-form` and then each function, I'm lost